# How to get actual height of 1 td?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id='tdleftcontent' style='border:1px solid red;'>
    <asp:Label ID='lbl' runat="server"></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

With control lbl, in code behind, I set text as 'img src='/CMS/Images/News/event1.JPG' border='0' />'

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lbl.Text = "<img alt='' src='/CMS/Images/News/event1.JPG' border='0' />";
    }
```

And in Javascript, I have a function to get HEIGHT of this td:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = document.getElementById('tdleftcontent').offsetHeight;
    alert(h);
});
```

But the result is: h=22px. It mean the image does not show up on web yet.
result picture:  http://upanh.nguoihoian.info/di-534E.jpg

Please help me in solve this problem.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<asp:placeholder>` instead of `<asp:label>`, and view the source in your browser to ensure the IMG tag is being created properly and that the SRC attribute actually exists.

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is showing up content in WYSWYG to web via lable (or <asp:Literal>).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3zw1470.aspx) control like so:

```
<asp:image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/CMS/Images/News/event1.JPG" BorderWidth="0" />
```

and for the JavaScript just grab the height using the jQuery [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    var h = $('#tdleftcontent').height();
    alert(h);
});
<script>
```

There are also innerHeight and outerHeight functions in jQuery for more specific needs.

EDITED: The others make a good point that the height value will not be available until the image is loaded.  If you don't want to wait until everything on the page is loaded, then you could create the image client side and attach to it's load event.  Just be careful to set the src attribute after the image is added the DOM.

.NET Code

```
this.lbl.Attributes["data-src"] = "/CMS/Images/News/event1.JPG";
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $td = $('#tdleftcontent');
    $('<img border="0" />')
        .bind('load', function() {
            $td.height();
            alert(h);
        })
        .bind('error', function() {
            $(this).hide();
        })
        .appendTo($td)
        .attr('src', $td.find('span').data('src'));
});
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Using window.load function help me through this problem. I'm very appriciated it.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `$(document).ready` in here. It will execute the handler on*DOM*ready, i.e. the image is usually not loaded then. Use `$(window).load` instead, or even better register the load handler on the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `$(document).ready()` executes your code once the DOM is ready. If you want to execute your code after the image is loaded then you should `$(window).load(function () {})`

Comment: Thanks. What I want is showing up content in WYSWYG to web via lable (or <asp:Literal>), and then getting td's height. Your suggestion definately helps me a lot. The td's height is exactly now.

Comment: If you got your answer correctly, then do not forget to accept it. :-)